# Python как достать название полей класса

Tags: python, классы

```
class W:
    def __init__(self, first, second):
        self.first = first
        self.second = second
```

как сделать output "first, second"

Comment: `w = W() w.__dict__.keys()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class W:
    def __init__(self, first, second):
        self.first = first
        self.second = second

w = W(1, 2)

result = ', '.join([attr for attr in dir(w) if not attr.startswith('__')])
result_value = ', '.join([str(getattr(w, attr)) for attr in dir(w) if not attr.startswith('__')])

print(result)   # first, second
print(result_value)   # 1, 2
```

Первый результат - все атрибуты класса.
Второй - все их значения.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!

Answer (score 1):

```
class W:
    def __init__(self, first, second):
        self.first = first
        self.second = second

W(None, None).__dict__.keys()
```